# How to use ltrace with wildcards

Tags: c++, c, linux, ltrace

I'm new to **ltrace**.

- I'd like to use wildcards (patterns) to trace function calls, but they don't seem to work as they should, based on the web pages I see, e.g. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html

E.g. this works:

```
ltrace -c -e "XDrawLine" -p 10876 ^C
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls      function
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------------------
100.00    4.925592         501      9829 XDrawLine
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------------------
100.00    4.925592                  9829 total
```

But this matches nothing:

```
trace -c -e "XDrawLin*" -p 10876
^C
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls      function
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------------------
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------------------
100.00    0.000000                     0 total
```

Also, no luck with  `-e "/XDrawLin.*/"` or `-e "XDrawLin.*"` either.
Any working example is appreciated.

- If this is sorted out, I'd like to move on to how to trace on C++ lib symbols, shall I use mangled or demangled format ?

Comment: you could pipe it into a grep and use wildcards..

Comment: grep-ping is no option because of the intensity of calls I'd like to trace. (If I run it without filters, it crashes the process :( )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality of the `-e` switch evolved over `ltrace` releases. Even fairly recent Linux releases frequently shipped an older ltrace, and that’s most likely is the issue for you. (For example, RHEL6 if I remember correctly, ships with version 0.5.) Run `ltrace --v` and make sure you have version 0.7 and above.

```
* Version 0.7.0 [2012-11-09 Fri]

** Tracing
...

*** Limited support for tracing returns from tail call functions

*** -e, -x and -l selectors now allow using globs and regular expressions
```

http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=collab-maint/ltrace.git;a=blob_plain;f=NEWS;hb=0.7.3

If you have an older ltrace - update it with your package manager or download it from http://freecode.com/projects/ltrace

Comment: Indeed, I upgraded from 0.5.3 to 0.7.3 and voila, my wildcards mentioned above now work ! Thanks.